# Using dask backend for joblib in a remote cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, joblib

How we can use dask for parallel computations on a remote clutser node, for example, PSC bridges. As an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from task.distributed import Client
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
import numpy as np

client = Client()             # create local cluster   LINE-1
# client = Client(processes=False)             # create local cluster LINE-2
# client = Client("scheduler-address:8786")  # or connect to remote cluster

def get_acc(X, y, i):

   X_ =X[i]
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
       X_, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

   clf = LogisticRegressionCV(
           n_jobs=5,
           cv = 5,
           max_iter=1000,
           solver='liblinear',
           penalty='l1').fit(
           X_train, y_train)
   return clf.score(X_test, y_test)

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10000, n_classes=2)
X = np.repeat(X[None,:,:], 150, axis=0)
num_cores = 30
with parallel_backend('dask'):
   scores = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, verbose=100)(
               delayed(get_acc)
               (X, y, i)
               for i in range(25)
           )
```

On creating local cluster using LINE-1, the node memory (512GB) gets full and it does not start any computations. On using second line (LINE-2), I get “OSError: timed out connecting to improc://10.8.10.235/791270/1 after 10s"

But this dask parallel works perfectly fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that could have worked on your laptop. In this

```
from task.distributed import Client
```

`task` should be `dask`.